# Create Back browser event using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a back button browser event using jquery. I did this code but it doesnt appear to work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.back').click(function() {
    window.history.back();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
```

Comment: Please define "_it doesn't work_".

Comment: Maybe use `event.preventDefault()` as well? I haven't tried it, but I wonder if the default action of appending `#` to the URL is essentially negating the `history.back()` call.

Answer (score 1):

The `href="#"` will add a new item to history, so `window.history.back();` will "return" to the page where the link was clicked. You need to prevent the link from directing to `#` with this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

     $('.back').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.history.back();
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing to specify `event` as function argument, try this one..

```
$(".back").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.back(1);
});
```

This might solve your problem.